# DoubleAnimation does not update DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, storyboard, windows-store-apps, dependency-properties

I have following class:

```
public class BindableClock : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = 0.0d,
        To = 10.0d,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromDays(1d)),
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
    private Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard { Duration = Duration.Automatic };


    public double BogusDouble
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BogusDoubleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BogusDoubleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BogusDouble.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BogusDoubleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BogusDouble", typeof(double), typeof(BindableClock), new PropertyMetadata(0.0d, BogusDoubleChangedCallback));

    public static void BogusDoubleChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var clock = d as BindableClock;
        clock.TimeSpan = clock.storyboard.GetCurrentTime();
    }


    public TimeSpan TimeSpan {get; set;}

    public BindableClock(bool start)
    {
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "BogusDouble");
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Value = TimeSpan.ToString(Format);
        if (start)
            storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        storyboard.Stop();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting, that after I run `Begin()` method, `BogusDouble` property will be updated few times and `BogusDoubleChangedCallback` will be risen each time. But it does not.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The duration of you storyboard should be one day? I think that would take some time until the first change will occur. Or do i miss something here...?

Comment: During one second it should change for around 0.0001, so if it would work i would see this change